# Injecting user on Spring Data JPA queries

Tags: spring-security, spring-data-jpa, spring-data

I´ve largely used JPA and Hibernate, but I'm relativy new to Spring Data JPA. I'm trying to inject the user logged so queries get visibility restriction upon user.

Let's say we have this entity:

```
public class Group {
    private String code;
    private String name;
    private String creationUserId;
}
```

And CreationUserId is a FK to the column Id of entity User. This tries to represent that this group should only be accessed to the user whose Id equals this creationUserId.

So, taking into account I'm using JWT (the subject on the token is the userID) and springSecurity (so the user is in `SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication()`), is there any fancy way of doing something like

```
public List<Groups> findMyGroups () {
    return groupsRepository.findMyGroups();
}
```

using the capabilities SpringDataJPA gives us?

Im trying to avoid doing something like

```
public List<Groups> findMyGroups () {
    MyUser u = (MyUser)SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails();
    return groupsRepository.findGroupsByUserCreationId(u.getId());
}
```

I don't have a problem on doing so, but it would result in such boilerplate, and maybe there is some workaround for achieving it.

Of course I don't want this on every single query, just in somes (there are two different security roles for listing, group:readAll and group:readMine).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spring Security provides integration with Spring Data to achieve what you want. Take a look at the [reference documentation about that](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/reference/servlet/integrations/data.html).

In short, you have to add the dependency and expose a Bean of type `SecurityEvaluationContextExtension`, like so:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-security-data</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

```java
@Bean
public SecurityEvaluationContextExtension securityEvaluationContextExtension() {
    return new SecurityEvaluationContextExtension();
}
```

When you have this, you can use the `Authentication` in your queries:

```java
@Query("SELECT g FROM Group g WHERE g.creationUserId = ?#{principal?.id}")
List<Group> readMine();
```

Comment: Yass!! This was exactly what i was looking for. Knew it must exist, but wasn't able to found it. Thank u so much!

On the other hand, do u know if there is a keyword for using it on method names? Or am I forzed to use it with a @Query annotation? I don't mind using it, but it may be handy having it.

Comment: I don't think so, but I maybe wrong. The javadoc for `SecurityEvaluationContextExtension`  says that "By defining this object as a Bean, Spring Security is exposed as SpEL expressions for creating Spring Data queries", so nothing related to method name resolver.